# SensorManager what is the GRAVITY_EARTH?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I found this values in sources.

```
 /** Standard gravity (g) on Earth. This value is equivalent to 1G */
    public static final float STANDARD_GRAVITY = 9.80665f;

    /** Sun's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_SUN             = 275.0f;
    /** Mercury's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_MERCURY         = 3.70f;
    /** Venus' gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_VENUS           = 8.87f;
    /** Earth's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_EARTH           = 9.80665f;
    /** The Moon's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_MOON            = 1.6f;
    /** Mars' gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_MARS            = 3.71f;
    /** Jupiter's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_JUPITER         = 23.12f;
    /** Saturn's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_SATURN          = 8.96f;
    /** Uranus' gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_URANUS          = 8.69f;
    /** Neptune's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_NEPTUNE         = 11.0f;
    /** Pluto's gravity in SI units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_PLUTO           = 0.6f;
    /** Gravity (estimate) on the first Death Star in Empire units (m/s^2) */
    public static final float GRAVITY_DEATH_STAR_I    = 0.000000353036145f;
    /** Gravity on the island */
    public static final float GRAVITY_THE_ISLAND      = 4.815162342f;
```

But i can't find any usages of this.
What the goal to use this values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure these are meant as jokes. I think it's unlikely that you'll find an Android device running on the [Death Star I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Star), mostly because the spaceship was blown up in the [Battle of Yavin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DS-1_Orbital_Battle_Station):

[image: Death Star]

The `STANDARD_GRAVITY` value is the amount of gravity you'll find on Earth, which is a bit more useful. All of these can be used with the gravity sensor (`Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY`): your sensor should pick up about `STANDARD_GRAVITY` worth of gravity in one direction.

For more about the gravity sensor, see [the Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html). For more about the Death Star, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Star), and for more about this mysterious island, try [Google](http://google.com/search?q=4%208%2015%2016%2023%2042).

Answer (score 1):

These are the gravitational constants for the various planets.

Objects, when dropped, accelerate at the rate of 9.8 m/s^2 on earth (independent of mass, in a vacuum).  This is basic physics.

For example, after two seconds, in the absence of air resistance, an object reaches a speed of 9.8 m/s^2 * 2 s = 19.6 m/s.